# How to show progress dialog in Android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I  want to show `ProgressDialog` when I click on Login button and it takes time to move to another page. How can I do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Please note: `ProgressDialog` class was deprecated in API 26 (Oreo). Instead of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like [ProgressBar](https://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar), which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively, you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress. Follow the Material design guidelines for [Progress & Activity](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You better try with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Sample code -

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public YourAsyncTask(MyMainActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // do background work here
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         // do UI work here
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above code in your Login Button Activity. And, do the stuff in `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`

**Update:**

`ProgressDialog` is integrated with `AsyncTask` as you said your task takes time for processing.

**Update:**

`ProgressDialog` class was deprecated as of API 26

Comment: He want to show progress dialog,not want use AsyncTask i think

Comment: @AmeerHamza Updated the answer.

Comment: Anyway, AysncTask is deprecated. Kindly update your answer.

Answer (score 112):

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
pd.setMessage("loading");
pd.show();
```

And that's all you need.

Comment: ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
pd.setMessage("loading");
pd.show();now showing anything.what to do.

Comment: You will need to use your actual `Activity` rather than the `yourActivity`.

Answer (score 30):

To use `ProgressDialog` use the below code

```
ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
```

To start the `ProgressDialog` use

```
progressdialog.show();
```

`progressdialog.setCancelable(false);` is used so that `ProgressDialog` cannot be cancelled until the work is done.

To stop the `ProgressDialog` use this code (when your work is finished):

```
progressdialog.dismiss();`
```

Answer (score 20):

Point one you should remember when it comes to [Progress dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is that you should run it in a separate thread. If you run it in your UI thread you'll see no dialog.

If you are new to [Android Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) then you should learn about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Which helps you to implement a [painless Threads](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

sample code

```
private class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(IncidentFormActivity.this);
        String typeStatus;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //set message of the dialog
            asyncDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingtype));
            //show dialog
            asyncDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //don't touch dialog here it'll break the application
            //do some lengthy stuff like calling login webservice

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //hide the dialog
            asyncDialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Your note that "progress dialog won't work on main UI thread" was what made my day. Thank you.

Comment: OnPreExecute and onPostExecute is run on the main thread. And you are starting and stoping the progress dialog from the main thread.

Answer (score 8):

Simple coding in your `activity` like below:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);    
dialog.setMessage("please wait...");
dialog.show();
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 6):

Declare your progress dialog:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

To start the progress dialog:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Please Wait...", true);
```

To dismiss the Progress Dialog :

```
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 3):

ProgressDialog is now officially deprecated in Android O. I use DelayedProgressDialog from https://github.com/Q115/DelayedProgressDialog to get the job done.

Usage:

```
DelayedProgressDialog progressDialog = new DelayedProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the good way to use dialog

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(IncidentFormActivity.this);

   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //set message of the dialog
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //show dialog
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

   protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
    // do background work here
    return null;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     // do UI work here
     if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
       dialog.dismiss()
     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call in oncreate()

```
new LoginAsyncTask ().execute();
```

Here how to use in flow..

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  private class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

     protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // Parsse response data
        return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //move activity
        super.onPostExecute(result);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
ProgressDialog dialog = 
   ProgressDialog.show(yourActivity.this, "", "Please Wait...");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
pd.show();
```

Comment: While this does provide a direct answer to the question, this would typically considered low quality on Stack Overflow because it provides no context or explanation. Please consider expanding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:Creata a XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Progress Dialog"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:Create a SampleActivity.java**

```
package com.scancode.acutesoft.telephonymanagerapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgress);
        btnProgress.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SampleActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait data is Processing");
        progressDialog.show();

//        After 2 Seconds i dismiss progress Dialog

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  final ProgressDialog loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
     "Fetching BloodBank List","Please wait...",false,false);  // for  showing the 
    // dialog  where context is the current context, next field is title followed by
    // message to be shown to the user and in the end intermediate field
    loadingDialog.dismiss();// for dismissing the dialog
```

for more info
[Android - What is difference between progressDialog.show() and ProgressDialog.show()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748617/android-what-is-difference-between-progressdialog-show-and-progressdialog-sh)

Answer (score 1):

ProgressDialog is deprecated since API 26

still you can use this:

```
public void button_click(View view)
{
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this,"Please Wait","Processing...",true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way :

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); //Your Activity.this
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...!");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(Inishlog.this, contentTitle, "even geduld aub....", true);//please wait....

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Barcode_edit.setText("");
                showAlert("Product detail saved.");


            }

        };

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
         } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want **ProgressDialog** call this method

```
    private void startLoader() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);    //ProgressDialog
    progress.setTitle("Loading");
    progress.setMessage("Please wait");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(7000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ProgressDialog in Java:

Note: Used with Android 33.

```
private AlertDialog progressAlertDialog = createProgressDialog(currentActivity / this);

private AlertDialog createProgressDialog(AppCompatActivity currentActivity) {
    LinearLayout vLayout = new LinearLayout(currentActivity);
    vLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    vLayout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
    vLayout.addView(new ProgressBar(currentActivity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge));

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setView(vLayout)
            .create();
}

public void displayProgressDialog() {
    if (!progressAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressAlertDialog.show();
    }
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    progressAlertDialog.dismiss();
}
```