# Android - What is difference between progressDialog.show() and ProgressDialog.show()?

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I mean, what is difference between return value of ProgressDialog static method show() and the non-static method show of an instance of that class?

Is there any reason to prefer this strategy

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
pd.setTitle(mTitle);
pd.setMessage(mMessage);
pd.show();
```

to this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity,mTitle,mMessage);
```

for a particular situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the "correct" method would depend on your usage.  The static `show( ... )` methods are performing the same steps you are:

```
public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message) {
    return show(context, title, message, false);
}

public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
}

public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
}

public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

You can see that any calls to the static `show` methods **with** parameters just ends up constructing a ProgressDialog and will call the instance method `show()`.

Using the static `show( ... )` methods just make it convenient for you to display a basic ProgressDialog using one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

writing it with capital p is the correct way to go since the method **show** is static

```
ProgressDialog.show(mActivity,mTitle,mMessage);
```

see the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

[image]

> *Is there any reason to prefer this strategy??*

the reason why is the best way to go is that 
static methods should always be accessed in a static way

Comment: Actually, the `show()` method is not static.  It is an instance method in `Dialog`.

Comment: The doc says it is static

Comment: Oh. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: kurtacious is right. In [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) (a super type of [`ProgressDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)) there also exists a [`show`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()) method that is not static (and takes no arguments). OP asks for the difference between those two methods.

Comment: OP's question was about the difference between the two methods, not how you should call a static method.  Regarding the `show()` method being non-static, See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()