# 'Running something in background inside a dialog

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background-process

I have some codes like this:

```
ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = subs.get(position).getTeachers();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                    builder.setView(v);

ListView listViewDialog = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_lv);
TesAdapter adapter1 = new TesAdapter(MainActivity.this, teachers);
listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter1);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
listViewDialog.setDivider(null);

builder.show();
```

This operation takes a lot of time. So, I am trying to show a ProgressDialog while it is loading. then to hide the progressbar and show this AlertDialog.

I have tried these:

[How to show progress dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446125/how-to-show-progress-dialog-in-android)

[How can I run code on a background thread on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472383/how-can-i-run-code-on-a-background-thread-on-android)

But none of them worked :( any solution?

Comment: Why do you call `notifyDataSetChnaged()` after setting adapter? it only has to be called when the data changed in the set adapter.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom dialog extending `DialogFragment`?