# ProgressDialog Before AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android

In Screen have `Button.` Once Use click on `Button` an `AsyncTask` will execute and fetch the data from database and show in the `AlertDialog.` Between ButtonClick and `AlertDialog` time needs to show `CircularProgressBar.`

My code is written below but Progress bar is not showing.

Any other workaround for the requirement.

```
 public void Select_PaymentMonths(String selectFlatNumber)
   {

    /*
    progressBarLoadData = new ProgressDialog(get ApplicationContext());
    progressBarLoadData.setMessage("Please Wait....");
    progressBarLoadData.show();
    */
  //  ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  //  progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait......");
 //   progressDialog.show();
    //monthProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   //ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    //  progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait......");
    ProgressDialog progressDialog =   ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please Wait","Wait for loading Payment Month data");

    residentsPaymentInfo = new ArrayList<UserPaymentInfo>();
    ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails = new 
     ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse();
    try {
    residentsPaymentInfo = 
            getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails.execute(selectFlatNumber).get();
        //monthProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        int notPaidMonthsCount = residentsPaymentInfo.size();
        List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(int i=0; i<notPaidMonthsCount; i++ )
        {
            UserPaymentInfo userNotPaidMonthInfo = new UserPaymentInfo();
            userNotPaidMonthInfo = residentsPaymentInfo.get(i);

            //listItems.add(userNotPaidMonthInfo.getPaymentMonth() +","+ 
           userNotPaidMonthInfo.getPaymentoYear() +" - ₹" + 
            userNotPaidMonthInfo.getactualAmount() + "/-");
            listItems.add(userNotPaidMonthInfo.getPaymentMonth() +" "+ 
          userNotPaidMonthInfo.getPaymentoYear() +" ₹" + 
            userNotPaidMonthInfo.getactualAmount() + "/-");
        }

     final CharSequence[] items = listItems.toArray(new 
         CharSequence[listItems.size()]);
       // arraylist to keep the selected items
        final ArrayList seletedItems=new ArrayList();
        //progressBarLoadData.dismiss();
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Select Payment Month Year Amount")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
               indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            // If the user checked the item, add it to the 
               selected items
                            //seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                            seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                        } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                            // Else, if the item is already in the array, 
       remove it

    seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                        }
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("OK", new 
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Collections.sort(seletedItems);

                        String selectedMonths = "";
                        float totalAmount=0;
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < seletedItems.size(); i++) {
                            //selectedMonths = selectedMonths + items[(int)
          (seletedItems.get(i))];
                            selectedMonths = selectedMonths +             
  residentsPaymentInfo.get((int)seletedItems.get(i)).getPaymentMonth() +"-
 "+residentsPaymentInfo.get((int)seletedItems.get(i)).getPaymentoYear()+",";
                            totalAmount = totalAmount + 
residentsPaymentInfo.get((int)seletedItems.get(i)).getactualAmount();
                        }

                        paymentMonth.setText(selectedMonths);
                        amountPaid.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount));
                //selectedMonths.split(",");
                //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here

             }
       }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                  {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                    }
                }).create();
        //return 50;
        dialog.show();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     //   e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have update the code ProgressDialog code into Async task like below but  still progress dialog is not appearing.

```
      public class ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse extends 
     AsyncTask<String, Void, List<UserPaymentInfo>> {
     ProgressDialog pDialog;
      private Context MSAContext;
      public ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
           MSAContext = context;
         }

   @Override
       protected void onPreExecute(){
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MSAContext);
       pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
   @Override
    protected List<UserPaymentInfo> doInBackground(String... params){
  String flatNo = params[0];
 String urls = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/";
 List<UserPaymentInfo> residentsMonthlyPayments = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urls)
            .build();

    Response responses = null;

    try
    {
        responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String jsonData = responses.body().string();
        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("ResidentsInfo");

        int limit = jarray.length();

        for(int i=0;i<limit; i++)
        {
            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            if(object.getString("FlatNo").equals(flatNo) && object.getString("PaymentStatus").equals("notpaid")) {
                UserPaymentInfo residentMaintePayment = new UserPaymentInfo();
                UserInfo residentInfo = new UserInfo();
                residentInfo.setUserFlatNo(object.getString("FlatNo"));
                residentInfo.setUserName(object.getString("Name"));
                residentInfo.setUserEamil(object.getString("OwnerEmail"));
                residentMaintePayment.setResidentData(residentInfo);
                residentMaintePayment.setactualAmount(object.getLong("Actualamountneedtopay"));
                residentMaintePayment.setPaymentYear(object.getInt("Year"));
                residentMaintePayment.setPaymentMonth(object.getString("Month"));
                residentsMonthlyPayments.add(residentMaintePayment);
            }
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
      //  e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // ex.printStackTrace();
}
return residentsMonthlyPayments;
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<UserPaymentInfo> rusult){
super.onPostExecute(rusult);
    pDialog.dismiss();


}
```

}

In Maintask calling async task like below

```
ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails = new 
   ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse(this);
     try {
        residentsPaymentInfo = 
     getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails.execute(selectFlatNumber).get();
        //monthProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // progressDialog.dismiss();
         int notPaidMonthsCount = residentsPaymentInfo.size();
         List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Progress bar screen not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

How is the `ProgressDialog`suppose to Visible. You initialize and `dismiss()`  it inside same block . It will dismiss instantly after initialization .

See the Code below .

```
 residentsPaymentInfo = 
        getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails.execute(selectFlatNumber).get();
```

Here `residentsPaymentInfo` seems to be a `AsyncTask` or a `Executor` ultimately a background thread . So this will run on other thread and you code which is 'progressDialog.dismiss()' get executes right after initialization .

**Solution** :- Right now i have no idea what exactly your background task is . If its `AsyncTask` then show the progress in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`.
And you also need to wait until the request process to show the `AlertDialog`
at the end of result. So you have to use a callback . Read [Implementing a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly change your code, but give u a example.
Put your logical in Thread.runnable, then after finish your work, dismiss ProgressDialog .

http://indyvision.net/2015/08/android-tutorials-show-a-progress-dialog-while-loading-data/

```
//inside the runnable will be the logic that you want to run
    void showProgressDialog(final Context context, final Runnable runnable) {
        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title ...", "Info ...", true);
        //you usually don't want the user to stop the current process, and this will make sure of that
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runnable.run();
                //after he logic is done, close the progress dialog
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` never block your UI thread,it run in background.

```
residentsPaymentInfo =getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails.execute(selectFlatNumber).get();
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

here you have directly  call the `dismiss()` method,it will not wait for completion of  `getResidentsPaymentMonthDetails` it directly dismiss the dialog also `residentsPaymentInfo` is also null or blank.

you can display the dialog in `ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse`

```
 private class ResidentsPaymentInfoHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
             protected void onPreExecute(){
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.show();
             }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               //your logic
                return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String params){
                super.onPostExecute(params);
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

         }
```

Comment: I have change code to call ProgressDialog from Async task. But sitll the Progress Dialog not showing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this code

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this); 
pd.setMessage("loading"); 
pd.show();
```

Dismiss the progress dialog before alert dialog

```
pd.dismiss();
```

For further information

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446125/how-to-show-progress-dialog-in-android&ved=2ahUKEwjb4bbyy73ZAhUH66QKHQMgBtUQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3WUSL439tsqqdnbc7ED8HW